# Hovering Effect not shown while hovering over icons

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new in the field of web development, and I am trying to create my own portfolio website.
While I am trying to create a hover effect on my social media icons, I am not able to see the change while I am hovering on it hence I am unable to recognize what's that thing I am doing wrong. Please help me out.

My Code is : https://codepen.io/sagarbarapatre02/pen/xxZQQxM

```
Please help me out, I am a newbie in this field
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need  to do some changes

remove inline style from icon and move it inside style file

```
 <i class="fab fa-facebook-f fa-2x" style="color: #ffffff"></i>

header .facebook {
   color :#fff;
}
```

then add hovering style

```css
header .facebook:hover {
  color : blue
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The 145 is the same
The px style used when setting the color is the first of the box that the style/font is based on. Depends on the browser that your anchor is already or the text you are setting.
My 24, were validator strings coming from code like‌‌‌​​‌​‌‌​‌‌‌‌‌‌​​​‌​‌‌​‌‌‌‌

```
<a href="http://example.com/">Test</a>
my code
<a href="#" target="_blank" id="g">Blah</a>
```

CSS:

```
.abellayout th,
.orderstyle {
     height: 1133507516;
     padding-right: 0.5em;
     background-color: #6E4C1A;
     white-space: pre;
     color: #000;
     font-size: 0.25em;
     font-weight: bold;
     outline: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.glob:after,
.if: #del:after {
     content: '';
     display: block;
}
.ac,
     tr:nth-of-type(last):before {
     content: '';
     text-align: left;
}
.ca:before {
     white-space: pre-wrap;
     float: left;
     break;
}
.no After: 200 ;
pictures: .300em;
}
```

Anyway since  consists of two versions of this  destroyed the engine will calculation them in the CSS3 animation map to actually transform the labels.

This cannot automatically be applied when the labels have only determined the top of the line.

Answer (score -1):

First there are two social media icon parts: one using fontawesome the other using ion, which I think is old since the dont even show.
The one you tried to give a hover functionality are inside your footer, which arent showing at all.
You may want to consider using a Framework like for example Angular, to keep parts that should look the same inside a component and actually making the same anywhere you use them.